# WPF how to set stackpanel as resources and reuse it in TabControls

Tags: wpf

I am new to C# and WPF so please give me some ideas:

I have an WPF app used to display some stack panels,all stack panels default Visibility is set to collapsed and they will switch to visible according to the received data.

Now I want to make all these stack panels to resources so I can reuse it in some new added tab controls and stack panels.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ColorOption" Visibility="Collapsed">
  <TextBlock Text="Line Color" Style="{StaticResource ItemNameTextBlockStyle}"/>
  <Button Style="{StaticResource ColorButtonStyle}" Click="Color_Click">
    <Button.Content>
      <Rectangle x:Name="LineColorRect" Style="{StaticResource ColorSelectionRectangleStyle}" />
    </Button.Content>
  </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Above is one example of stack panels I am using. In the code behind the function "Color_Click" will change this "ColorOption" stack panel state and do something.

However after I try to put this stack panel into Windows.Resources

```
<Window.Resources>
  <StackPanel x:Name="ColorOption" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Key="ColorOption">
    <TextBlock Text="Line Color" Style="{StaticResource ItemNameTextBlockStyle}"/>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ColorButtonStyle}" Click="Color_Click">
      <Button.Content>
        <Rectangle x:Name="LineColorRect" Style="{StaticResource ColorSelectionRectangleStyle}" />
     </Button.Content>
    </Button>
  </StackPanel>
</Window.Resources> (I also put the style files inside)
```

In the tab controls I did

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem Header="Tab 1" Content="{StaticResource ColorOption}"/>
</TabControl>
```

The visual studio shows error in the code behind says "ColorOption does not exist in the current context"

How can I fix this? Is any way to set the context? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap the StackPanel in `ContentControl` and make it ControlTemplate.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ColorOptionTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ColorOption" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock Text="Line Color" Style="{StaticResource ItemNameTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ColorButtonStyle}" Click="Color_Click">
            <Button.Content>
                <Rectangle x:Name="LineColorRect" Style="{StaticResource ColorSelectionRectangleStyle}"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

However, you will need to change properties of controls inside the `ContentControl` and it would be cumbersome. So the StackPanel could be wrapped in `UserControl` instead.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.ColorOptionControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <StackPanel x:Name="ColorOption" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock Text="Line Color" Style="{StaticResource ItemNameTextBlockStyle}"/>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource ColorButtonStyle}" Click="Color_Click">
            <Button.Content>
                <Rectangle x:Name="LineColorRect" Style="{StaticResource ColorSelectionRectangleStyle}"/>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

This is a common way in WPF. The downside is that you will need to add dependency properties to `UserControl` and wire up them with dependency properties of internal controls so that you can set their values at the level of `UserControl` and bridge them with external controls and window. This could be complicated and cumbersome as well.

So I think ideally it would be better to find an existing control which has similar functionalities you want and create a custom control deriving from the existing one.